# How to replace text of tds instead of href

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table with multiple rows. and i have rows that each of them has a specific class. in the last row i have a link . how can i replace each td text infront of their name in link ?
i wrote the below code but it sets the texts at the end of my links.
here is my snippet :

```js
$(".list").each(function(index, element) {
 var route=$(this).closest("tr").find(".route").text()
 var airline=$(this).closest("tr").find(".airline").text()
 var route=$(this).closest("tr").find(".route").text()
 var linkk=$(this).attr("href")
 $(this).attr("href",linkk+route+airline+route); });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="route">tehran-istanbul</td>
<td class="airline">Iran air</td>
<td class="route">Ss 454</td>
<td><p class="date1">1398-5-12</p><p class="date2">(2017-08-23)</p></td>
<td><a href="page2.bc?route=&airline=&route=&date1=&date2=" class="list">link</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="route">tehran-Ankara</td>
<td class="airline">Tukish airline</td>
<td class="route">7547</td>
<td><p class="date1">1395-5-12</p><p class="date2">(2018-01-01)</p></td>
<td><a href="page2.bc?route=&airline=&route=&date1=&date2=" class="list">link</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: your question is not clear to me, what is the expected result?

Comment: just tell us the expected result

Comment: i want to add the text of each td . in front of their name in href values . for example : a href="page2.bc?airline=airlineoftd&route=routeoftd"

Comment: @Farsay i want to add the text of each td . in front of their name in href values . for example : a href="page2.bc?airline=airlineoftd&route=routeoftd"

Comment: @Dij i want to get the closest in each tr and put them in the closet tr link

Comment: `?route=something&route=something_else` will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

few issues with your code:

you are redeclaring variable route, will not be helpful in your case, instead initialize two vars route1 and route2.
`linkk+route+airline+route` won't give the string you need you will need to add extra strings like 'route=' to identify parameters in between.
`$(this).parents("tr").find(".route")` will give you multiple elements with class route, you need to target specific elements, you can use first() and last() in your case.

```js
$(".list").each(function(index, element) {
 var route1= "route=" + $(this).parents("tr").find(".route").first().text();
 var airline= "airline=" + $(this).parents("tr").find(".airline").first().text();
 var route2= "route=" + $(this).parents("tr").find(".route").last().text();
  var date1 = "date1=" + $(this).parents("tr").find(".date1").first().text();
  var date2 = "date2=" + $(this).parents("tr").find(".date2").first().text();
 var link = $(this).attr("href").replace(/\?.*/g, "?") + route1 + "&" + airline + "&" + route2  + "&" + date1 + "&" + date2;
 $(this).attr("href", link);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="route">tehran-istanbul</td>
<td class="airline">Iran air</td>
<td class="route">Ss 454</td>
<td><p class="date1">1398-5-12</p><p class="date2">(2017-08-23)</p></td>
<td><a href="page2.bc?route=&airline=&route=&date1=&date2=" class="list">link</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="route">tehran-Ankara</td>
<td class="airline">Tukish airline</td>
<td class="route">7547</td>
<td><p class="date1">1395-5-12</p><p class="date2">(2018-01-01)</p></td>
<td><a href="page2.bc?route=&airline=&route=&date1=&date2=" class="list">link</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How to Add date1 and date2 . is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 1):

Similar to @DiJ I slightly changed the name of one of your arguments (the second `route` to `routeno`). And then I basically tried to reduce the code to the minimum, making it simpler at the same time.

```js
$(".list").each(function(index, element) {
 ['route','airline','routeno'].forEach(function(i,o){console.log(i)});
 $(this).closest("tr").find("td").each((i,o)=>{
   if (vars.indexOf(o.className)>-1)
     this.href+=o.className+'='+encodeURIComponent(o.innerHTML)+'&';     
 });
 this.href+='date1=&date2=';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td class="route">tehran-istanbul</td>
<td class="airline">Iran air</td>
<td class="routeno">Ss 454</td>
<td><p class="date1">1398-5-12</p><p class="date2">(2017-08-23)</p></td>
<td><a href="page2.bc?" class="list">link</a></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="route">tehran-Ankara</td>
<td class="airline">Tukish airline</td>
<td class="routeno">7547</td>
<td><p class="date1">1395-5-12</p><p class="date2">(2018-01-01)</p></td>
<td><a href="page2.bc?" class="list">link</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

You can do the same also without the `indexOf()` testing, like

```
$(".list").each(function(index, lnk) {
 var $tr=$(lnk).closest("tr");
 ['route','airline','routeno'].forEach(function(col,i){
   lnk.href+=encodeURIComponent($tr.find("td."+col).text())+'&'; });
 lnk.href+='date1=&date2=';
});
```